# How do I make a container for a double a Semigroup?

Tags: haskell, derivingvia

I am learning Haskell. Imagine I have the following:

```
data Coordinate = Coordinate double
```

I wish to implement a semigroup instance for `Coordinate`.

```
instance Semigroup (Coordinate a) where
  Coordinate a <> Coordinate b   =  Coordinate (a+b)
```

The typechecker is displeased at me:

```
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Coordinate’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Semigroup’, namely ‘(Coordinate a)’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Semigroup (Coordinate a)’
    |
175 | instance (Num a) => Semigroup (Coordinate a) where
```

(I know that this is just an empty container for a double and I could already be using just the double itself, but I am learning Haskell and I would like to understand how this works.)

Comment: Does changing it to `instance Semigroup Coordinate` help?

Comment: [`DerivingVia`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html#extension-DerivingVia) - Without a type argument: `newtype Coordinate = Coordinate Double deriving (Semigroup, Monoid) via Sum Double` and with a type argument: `newtype Coordinate a = Coordinate a deriving (Semigroup, Monoid) via Sum a`. This will define `(<>)` using `(+)` and `mempty` with `0`.

Comment: `(+)` on the `Double` is not associativity, so it cannot be semigroup.

Comment: possibly a typo, but in the `data` declaration your `double` needs to be `Double`. (All types in Haskell must start with an uppercase letter.) Also, you probably want it to be a `newtype` rather than `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you specified `Coordinate`, it doesn't have any type parameters. So the semigroup instance head should be simply

```
instance Semigroup Coordinate where
  ...
```

Alternatively, you can give it a parameter to allow including different number types:

```
newtype Coordinate' a = Coordinate' { getCoordinate' :: a }
```

In this case, the `Semigroup` instance *will* need to mention the parameter, however just calling it `a` won't be enough because you can't perform `+` on arbitrary types. You need to either restrict it to `Double` there

```
instance Semigroup (Coordinate' Double)
```

or to an arbitrary *numerical* type

```
instance Num a => Semigroup (Coordinate' a)
```

---

Note that in either case, `Semigroup` may not be the best class for the purpose, consider using [`AdditiveGroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html) and then you can also make it a [`VectorSpace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html).

Comment: Thank you! `instance Semigroup Coordinate where` worked because `Coordinate` doesn't have any type parameters. I don't know why that was really hard for me to figure out. Thanks!